# Why does my formula not work unless I edit it first?

Tags: excel, formula

We have data that is imported from a text document, and depending on the age of the account, has more or less leading zeros. I wrote this formula to determine the zeroes and take appropriate action to strip them.

The numbers to be checked look like: #0000XXXXXXX (4 leading zeroes and 7 digits) or #000XXXXXXXX (3 leading zeroes and 8 digits). Our software needs the leading zeroes removed.

```
=IF(EXACT(LEFT(E1,5),"#0000"),RIGHT(E1,7),RIGHT(E1,8))
```

This used to work when I first wrote it. Now I have to turn it into this first ( I have to remove the value after the second comma):

```
=IF(EXACT(LEFT(E1,5),),RIGHT(E1,7),RIGHT(E1,8))
```

And then put the "#0000" back in order for the formula to work. If I don't, I get the "There's a problem with this formula"

Comment: Try the following simplified formula: `=--SUBSTITUTE(E1,"#","")`

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! I have never heard of using signs in front of the function.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I needed to strip off the last two digits as well. The new formula that works is: =--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,12),"#","")

Thanks again!

Comment: I have often found when taking numbers out of text, that if the last operation done by the formula is "*1" then it will work.